# What is the problem with this code snippet?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura.js

I wrote this code as JS controller of a component to invoke a VF Page but here it is showing that This error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
> Action failed: c:DataProcessor$controller$downloadDocument [sendDataProc is not a function]
> Failing descriptor: {c:DataProcessor$controller$downloadDocument}

```
({
 downloadDocument : function(component, event, helper){
     console.log("line 3");
  var sendDataProc = component.get("v.sendData");
     console.log(sendDataProc);
  var dataToSend = {
     "label" : "This is test"
  }; //this is data you want to send for PDF generation
console.log(dataToSend);
  //invoke vf page js method
   sendDataProc(dataToSend, function(){
             console.log('hello');
  });
 },
    
})
```

Comment: Aura or lwc? Looks like aura... What is sendData, a method from apex class? Do you have permissions to run this class? Is the apex class mentioned in aura component's top tag? Why do you call directly instead of "enqueueAction"?

Comment: It is an Aura component SendData Is an Attribute on Aura component with Object Type and here I want to invoke function on VF page from here but It is showing that sendDataProc is not defined function error, I want to resolve this code link is https://gist.github.com/toanshulverma/16244d19ac68364cb75443695d81403b